Calculating magnitude of basis vectors for polar coordinates
Let $M=\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ be a smooth manifold. Let $(U,\phi)$ be one of its coordinate charts where $U\subseteq M$ is open. Fix $p\in M$. Let $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\}$ be coordinate basis for the tangent space $T_p M$. They are basis for polar coordinates.
I wonder if it is possible to show that the magnitude of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ is $1$ and the magnitude of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ is $r$. I am not sure how magnitude is defined for differential operators.
I think one can use the metric tensor for polar coordinates $g$ for that. The magnitude squared of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ is $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}^\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial r}^\nu=1$. The magnitude squared of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ is $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}^\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}^\nu=r^2$.
However, the metric tensor is defined as
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\cdot$ represents dot product between coordinate basis vectors. Computing them requires one to know beforehand magnitudes of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$. So, the metric tensor strategy I proposed will not work because it's circular. Also, I am not sure how dot product is defined in this context.
Any other ideas?

Calculate the partial derivatives of the obvious parametrization $g(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial r}$, etc. Now use the induced inner product (Riemannian metric) on $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}\subset\Bbb R^2$.

Thanks but $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ is a derivation $D:C^\infty(M)\to\mathbb R$. In particular, it takes any smooth $f:M\to\mathbb R$ as input. The function $g$ you gave has $\mathbb R^2$ in its codomain.

Sure. Differentiate one coordinate function at a time.
